# Jhipster swagger configuration adding new Docket

Tags: swagger, jhipster

I have spring boot app generated by Jhipster. And it creates OpenApiConfiguration by default but when I change this class Nothing is changing. How can I change Jhipster OpenApiConfiguration and how can I add Docket for this configuration